# SIM868 powers down after few seconds

Tags: power-supply, power, gsm, modem, simcom

I designed a circuit with SIM868 module, and i followed the recommendation from datasheet to unsure suffusion current.

The main power supply is getting from VCC:12V source converted to 5V by an DC-DC step down converter that can output up to 3A, after that the voltage is reduced by tow diodes that also have output current up to 3A.

The following is the power supply circuit with battery charger:

[image: Power supply circuit]

And this is the module circuit diagram

[image: Module circuit]

I  wanted to test it and a problem occured. When I turn on the module, it automatically powers off after a few seconds.and sometimes if i remove SIM card or detach antenna, module stays on, So, I assume it powers down after it connects to network. and that can be because of power lack.

For that i added and external power source 3.7V that can output also more than 2A that is recommended by datasheet connected directly to module VDD pins, but the same problem occurs.

Did anyone have a problem like this and knows how to solve?

**Updates:**

I checked with the oscilloscope and I found that when the module tries to connect to the GSM network the voltage drops from 3.7 V to 2.75 V, even if I directly connected the power supply to the VDD pins of the module.

[image]

Oscilloscope configuration:

- 500mV / division
- 20us / division

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stated in the datasheet that the module will shut down in a few seconds if the supply voltage drops below `3V`.

[image: circuit_3]

The use of two diodes in series for dropping the voltage is not optimal since, their voltage drop is dependent on the current flowing through them. Considering their smallest voltage drop (2 x 200mV = 400mV), would would supply too much voltage (4.6V) to the module. Considering their highest voltage drop you have two scenarios:

1. With data mode GSM850 there's a current consumption of about 378mA, which causes a voltage drop of 2x300mV = 600mV. Hence, the supply voltage of the module is about 4.4V.
2. During Tx burst there's a 2A peak current. You would have to measure how much the voltage drop is with the aid of an osci. I reckon that is the problem which is causing your module to reset.

You can try adding more capacitance to the `VCC` pin of your module in order to prevent this voltage drop. However, the problem with the imprecise supply voltage still remains. If you are using the `5V` only to bias the IC charger, you could also modify the feedback of the IC `MP1484` so that the output voltage is `4.4V`, so that you wouldn't need to add the two diodes.

Comment: No, I did not use an SD card in this design, and the EXT_PWR is only used to detect whether the external power is there or not, it is connected to the microcontroller

Comment: How are you supplying the SD card?

Comment: I'm not actually using the SD card, it is not connected

Comment: Ok. I will edit my answer. Apparently you have a problem with your two diodes, which are causing the supply voltage to drop below 3V. I will update my answer.

Comment: @Hakraf My answer was updated.

Comment: Yes, I assumed also it's because of voltage drop and bad power supply, that's why i connected a bench power supply regulated to 4V directly to the module VDD pins, but the same problem occurs

Comment: Did you measure the voltage with an oscilloscope? Sometimes even some power supplies are not able to deliver a lot of current without having some voltage drop. That's why low esr capacitor are used in such places.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108621/discussion-between-hakraf-and-vtolentino).